# How to count decimal places of float?

Tags: casting, go, floating-point-precision

I want to check if a float32 has two decimal places or not. My javascript way to do this would look like:

```
step  := 0.01
value := 9.99

if int(value/step) % 1 == 0 {
    printf("has two decimal places!")
}
```

The above example also works. However it will not work when step is incorrect as go then cannot properly cast from float64 to int.

Example:

```
step  := 0.1
value := 9.99

if int(value/step) % 1 == 0 {
    printf("has two decimal places!")
}
```

Compiler Error: `constant 9.99 truncated to integer`

When we use dynamic values it will just return true for every case.

**So what is the appropriate way to count decimal places?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int value % 1 is always zero!

I suggest an alternative way:

```
value := float32(9.99)
valuef := value*100
extra := valuef - float32(int(valuef))
if extra < 1e-5 {
    fmt.Println("has two decimal places!");
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/LQQ8T6SIY2

**Update**

```
package main

import (
    "math"
)

func main() {
    value := float32(9.9990001)

    println(checkDecimalPlaces(3, value))
}

func checkDecimalPlaces(i int, value float32) bool {
    valuef := value * float32(math.Pow(10.0, float64(i)))
    println(valuef)
    extra := valuef - float32(int(valuef))

    return extra == 0
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/jXRhHsCYL-

Comment: is it possible to make this more dynamic? How would this look as a function with dynamic steps? With your example I would need to hardcode `100` and `1e-5`.

Comment: @bodokaiser see update, but it will fail when value is very close to 9.99 like 9.990000001

Comment: Thank you. Don't mind if I leave the question open a bit. Else I am marking it later :)

Comment: `checkDecimalPlaces(3, value)` gives true if values is 9.12 for example.

Answer (score 9):

You have to trick it, add an extra variable:

```
step := 0.1
value := 9.99
steps := value / step
if int(steps)%1 == 0 {
    fmt.Println("has two decimal places!")
}
```

Or cast your steps before you convert it to int like:

```
int(float64(value / step))
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/iO0upLKvWe)

//edit

the hacky non-mathematical way is to convert it to a string and split it, example:

```
func NumDecPlaces(v float64) int {
    s := strconv.FormatFloat(v, 'f', -1, 64)
    i := strings.IndexByte(s, '.')
    if i > -1 {
        return len(s) - i - 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/2gDAcnn2nq)

//updated with a minor optimization

Comment: Check the update, added a "hacky" version, more equivalent of how you do it in python / javascript.

Comment: if I change 9.99 to 9.9 in your first playground, it still says its 2DP

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to get the decimal portion of a float. Can use `len(decimalPortion(n))` to get the number of decimal places.

```
func decimalPortion(n float64) string {
    decimalPlaces := fmt.Sprintf("%f", n-math.Floor(n)) // produces 0.xxxx0000
    decimalPlaces = strings.Replace(decimalPlaces, "0.", "", -1) // remove 0.
    decimalPlaces = strings.TrimRight(decimalPlaces, "0") // remove trailing 0s
    return decimalPlaces
}
```

Check it out in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Jw70yzc8sX2)

Comment: This doesn't work correctly for exponential notation.
For example, 5e-06 is same as 0.000005 but will produce different answers with this solution.